# JSTL Expression Language accessing object properties

Tags: methods, jstl, el, getter

I was following a tutorial today that had me scratching my head for an hour. Consider:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int getTotal() {
        amount = 100;
        return amount;
    }
}
```

and an excerpt from a JSP:

```
<p>Total: ${objectOfTypeMyClass.total}</p> //object instantiated elsewhere
```

Nowhere in the code was an instance variable named "**total**" ever declared or used. The only reference to the word "total" in the whole project (other than in the JSP) was the method **getTotal()**.

So after some desperate last-ditch experimentation, it appears that Expression Language evaluates **${someObject.var}** as "call the **getVar()** method of the **someObject** object.

I worked with this long tutorial for over a week thinking that **${someObject.var}** was saying "directly fetch the saved instance variable "**var**" from **someObject**.

Did I have it wrong the whole time and is my observation correct that in order to reference any instance variable using EL, you have to provide a corresponding getter method named **getVarname()** where "**Varname**" is the name of the instance variable?

Also, EL seems to be case-insensitive in this regard. In my example above, "total" in **${objectOfTypeMyClass.total}** is all lowercase where the method **getTotal()** has a capital "T".

And while we're at it, why don't we need to instantiate the variable "total"? I guess EL isn't actually referencing an instance variable...just a getter method?

What gives?

Comment: Consider registering your account. Your [other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/451175/chrism) is now fully decoupled. Unregistered accounts can only be accessed/reused by using the same PC/webbrowser as long as the cookies aren't cleared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Did I have it wrong the whole time and is my observation correct that in order to reference any instance variable using EL, you have to provide a corresponding getter method named getVarname() where "Varname" is the name of the instance variable?

That's correct. EL adheres the [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) as described in the [EL specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/expression_language-2.2-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/expression_language-2_2-mrel-spec.pdf).

> Also, EL seems to be case-insensitive in this regard. In my example above, "total" in ${objectOfTypeMyClass.total} is all lowercase where the method getTotal() has a capital "T".

No, it's certainly not case insensitive. It's specified behaviour. `${bean.Total}` would not have worked.

> And while we're at it, why don't we need to instantiate the variable "total"? I guess EL isn't actually referencing an instance variable...just a getter method?

It's because it's supposed to adhere the Javabean specification.

All with all, read the both specifications and everything will be clear :)

#### See also:

- [What are the advantages of Javabeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461199/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-java-beans/3461364#3461364)

Answer (score 2):

The `.` in `objectOfTypeMyClass.total` is the JSTL EL Dot Operator. It can do a few different things. Including:

1. `map.key` accessed a value from `map` stored under `key`. or
2. `object.property` accesses `property` from `object` using "JavaBeans" conventions.

Comment: I guess I sort of made an a** out of....well....just me...by assuming that the use of the dot operator in EL is the same as in Java (at least when accessing a variable of an object). Functionally in the end I guess it is (i.e. will give you the desired property), but mechanically I can see that it's not the same under the hood (gets it the JavaBean way). Thanks for the answer z5h

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int total = 100;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You would probably want a setter method too so that total won't have to be 100 all the time.