# How EL and Lombok work together for getters and setters

Tags: jstl, lombok

I'm a little confused with how Lombok and JSTL work on getters and setters.
I have the following @Data class:

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    private boolean isStateOne;
}
```

And I can access the private boolean in .jsp like this:

```
<c:set var="state" value="${foo.stateOne}"/>
```

While I can also declare the private boolean as

```
private boolean stateOne;
```

and access it in JSTL the same way. However, the following code will throw PropertyNotFoundException:

```
<c:set var="state" value="${foo.StateOne}"/>
```

Can anyone clarify what naming convention I should use when working with JSTL and Lombok at the same time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772430/jstl-expression-language-accessing-object-properties

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? The problem you are facing is EL related, not JSTL related. It is the EL expression that causes the property not being resolved. Having the wrong tags and wording will decrease the change of getting an answer.

Comment: The `PropertyNotFoundException` is expected in you second expression since it's incorrect. It should be `${foo.stateOne}`. See also the top answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should use classic Java convention.
Its a problem with generation getters for boolean fields:

For private boolean isStateOne getter is a:

```
public boolean isStateOne() {
        return isStateOne;
  }

 public void setStateOne(boolean stateOne) {
        isStateOne = stateOne;
  }
```

For private boolean stateOne getter is a:

```
public boolean isStateOne() {
    return stateOne;
}

public void setStateOne(boolean stateOne) {
    this.stateOne = stateOne;
}
```

In the both of this declarations the getter has a name: isStateOne
Try Use:

```
<c:set var="state" value="${foo.isStateOne}"/>
```

Instead a StateOne