# What is the advantage of java beans over POJOs in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, pojo

I am quite new to the Spring framework, so I apologise for the stupid question. I have been learning about Java beans; I have also been reading about how the Spring Framework is a bean container and how there are different types of beans ([What is the advantage of using Java Beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461199/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-java-beans)).

However, I still don't get why they are so powerful. If we wanted to, say, create a Spring web app, couldn't we just do it without the use of beans, but just using POJOs? What are really the advantages of using Java beans over POJOs?

Comment: They're opposites of one another.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils They are *not*. A java bean is a POJO that follows some naming conventions and other constraints.

Comment: @Andreas, OK. So perhaps opposite is the wrong word but seems a little nit picky. But that's what I was getting at. A bean is a bean; it has a contract that must be met (get,set, etc.). A POJO is not restricted in such a manner.

Answer (score 4):

JavaBean can be or generally is a POJO even vice versa is true.
The only difference is Java bean follows [certain conventions](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) whereas POJO doesn't necessarily need to follow any conventions.

You can refer this link: [Beans vs POJO](http://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/).
From above link:

> Spring managed objects are referred to as beans is because in the very
>   early versions, Spring was intended only for use with JavaBeans. That
>   is no longer the case of course: Spring can manage just about any
>   object, even if it doesn’t have JavaBean type characteristics such as
>   default constructors or mutator methods (getters and setters). None
>   the less, the term ‘Spring beans’ has stuck.

Comment: why does spring focus on java beans instead of pojos though?

Comment: what does it mean that the spring framework "manages" beans then? For example, that spring manages the number of instantiations of a class?

Comment: @user3289157 Manage can mean many things, but it mostly refers to managing the life cycle of the object, meaning the creation and destruction of the object. If the bean implements certain interfaces, and/or annotates methods with certain annotations, the bean can be notified by Spring when certain events happen. For examples, see this article: [Spring Bean Life Cycle Methods](http://www.journaldev.com/2637/spring-bean-life-cycle-methods-initializingbean-disposablebean-postconstruct-predestroy-aware-interfaces).

Comment: See the spring supports dependency injection through setters and constructor, a java bean has a convention regarding setters and constructors, whereas POJO doesn't need to. So this makes spring more favorable to Javabean.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no crucial advantages. To explain a bit,

There are 3 things that you have to clarify,

1. JavaBeans

JavaBeans are simply Java classes which adhere to certain coding conventions

2. POJO (Plain Old Java Object)
3. Spring Beans

Spring beans are objects created and managed by the Spring framework.

None of the 3 terms discussed are mutually exclusive. A Java object can be a JavaBean, a POJO and a Spring bean all at the same time. All in all JavaBean is a special case of the POJO. There are no special powers to JavaBeans over POJOs inside the Spring container.

Answer (score 0):

There are some contracts for JavaBean , like it should have public default constructor and getter setter, Serializable needs to be implemented.

But in case of POJO there is no such contracts. Its simpler than JavaBean

Answer (score 0):

Writing your application using Spring beans can also make your application easier to test using mocking frameworks such as Mockito. You can use either mocks or stub implementations in your  junit classes.

Without a managed bean container, a given class would need to instantiate all it's dependent objects - which makes it difficult to write unit tests for that class - it can be done, but it's harder.

With a dependency injection framework you can simply call the setters for your dependent object yourself in your unit tests using mock objects.